# Mapping numbers in some interval uniquely

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it true that for some interval of natural numbers $1...a$ and some prime $p<a-1$, where $a$ and $p$ are coprime, then $pn\pmod a$ for $n=1$ to $a$ uniquely maps the numbers to the same interval in a different way? If so, how would I go about proving this?

Comment: Take $p = 2$ and $a = 4$; then $2$ and $4$ are mapped into $0$, so I think you may have gotten the bounds on $a$ and $p$ wrong.

Comment: Perhaps for $p>2$?

Comment: Take $p=3, a=6$, then $4,6$ are mapped into $0$. I think you meant $a < p$, then  the $an \mod p$ are unique

Comment: What if gcd(a,p) = 1, since if they are multiples of each other you will get 0s

Comment: Then you are fine!

Comment: Ok nice - how exactly might I go about proving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a, b$ be two positive integers such that $gcd(a, b) = 1$. Let $a > b$.

We will show that $n \mapsto bn $ (all $\mod a$) is a permutation of the numbers $1, \cdots, a$.

First, by the euclidean algorithm, there exist $r, s$ such that $ra + sb = 1$; taking that expression $\mod a$ we get $sb \equiv 1 \mod a$ which is the same as saying that $b$ is invertible. Now suppose

$$bn_1 \equiv bn_2 \mod a$$

Because $s$ is the inverse of $b$, we get

$$sbn_1 \equiv sbn_2 \iff n_1 \equiv n_2 \mod a$$

If $n_1,n_2 < a$, then it follows that $n_1 = n_2$ and thus our map is injective in $0, \cdots a-1$ which can be also seen as $1, \cdots, a$